# CSS transform with Flash content

Tags: css, flash, transform, scale

i have a web application that runs inside a iframe.
The iframe is scaled with -webkit-transform:scale(0.8), thats works pretty good but my flash audio recorder inside that iframe doesn´t work when the iframe gots scaled. The flash selfs got loaded and works but the SecurityPanel on which the user has to allow the access to the microphone, is not clickable.

Maybee someone has the same problem or any idea what i can do to fix that?

Thanks

Comment: Is the css transform a must? Can't you just give the iframe smaller dimensions and adjust the flash, so that it scales?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, the page on which the iframe is displayed, uses the transform scale for autosize the page to the client browser size.

Comment: Can you read the css transform and revert it in the iframe, so `0.8`  is outside scale and inside scale is `1/0.8 = 1.25` which adds up to be a scale of 1?

Comment: No its not working, its seems to be an problem with the zoom. You can try it here: http://hmreimers.de/recorder/

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you can set the flash's wmode to `window`, you would force it to be display in top of everything. There wouldn't be anything to prevent the user from clicking on the SecurityPanel.

Comment: No its not working. 
You can try it @ hmreimers.de/recorder/ i added a new button for that.
The flash disapperas when wmode set to window.
I found a couple of open bugs for firefox and chrome with the same descriptions. 
So i think the website developer has to change there transform.
Thanks